# Creating a Python specific settings

Tags: windows, vim

In this [**tutorial**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YhqsjUUHj6g) many setting are configured so `Vim` works well with `Python`. I'd like to use some of the settings only on Python files as I will also use the editor to edit lots of sql files.

Is this the correct way to create Python specific settings?

1. Create a file `python.vim` and locate it in the following directory:
   `M:\vimfiles\after\ftplugin\`
2. Add the following to the file:

> ```
>  setlocal tw=79
>  setlocal colorcolumn=80
>  setlocal highlight Colorcolumn ctermbg=233
> ```

Do I need to use `setlocal` or will `set` suffice? Is `setlocal highlight` correct syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mostly right. The use of `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` is strictly only necessary for settings from the default `ftplugin/python.vim` file that you want to **overrule**, but it's also okay to put other Python-related stuff in there. If it gets out of hand, you can split off things into e.g. `~/.vim/ftplugin/python_tools.vim` or `.../python/mappings.vim` (see `:help ftplugin-name`).

#### setlocal

Yes, you need to use `:setlocal`, otherwise your settings will leak into other buffers opened from the Python buffer.

#### colorcolumn

The `'colorcolumn'` setting is *window*-local, not *buffer*-local. Filetype plugins should change buffer settings (as the filetype is associated with a buffer, and windows can display different buffers during their lifetime). Therefore, it may happen that the colorcolumn will persist when you, say, edit a Java file in the same window. You'd need to set up elaborate autocmds to make this fully work, but depending on your workflow, you may never be affected by this, or just don't bother.

```
:setlocal highlight Colorcolumn ctermbg=233
```

Highlighting is global; you cannot simply prefix `setlocal`, this won't work! Just define the color with `:highlight` once in your `~/.vimrc` or color scheme, and it'll suffice. Changing the color per filetype would again require autocmds to fully work.

Comment: +1 ok - so I don't want to overrule any of the recommendations in the default python.vim file so I will move these setting to `$HOME/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim` also decided to not bother with the `highlight` recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

I store my Python-specific settings is in `$HOME/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim`, since I do nothing to conflict with `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim`. If you want to overrule what the ftplugins with your Vim distribution set up, then `$HOME/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` is what you want, as it is read afterwards.

`setlocal` will set a variable for the specific buffer. This means that if you open a [c](/questions/tagged/c) file, in the same session, it won't inherit these settings. I would recommend using `setlocal`.